# Is Java ByteCode has "indirect jump"?

Tags: java, assembly, x86, bytecode

if i was not wrong, It seems that all the control flow bytecode in Java

like

```
ifeq
goto
```

and others are direct jump instructions.

my questions is, is there any "indirect jump" instructions in Java?

And if not, how can I simulate a "indirect jump" in Java using JavaByte code like in assembly we can do this:

```
goto address;  // we can only know address at runtime
```

Thank you

------------------update--------------------------

basically, what i am trying to do is to change my control flow at runtime, but as 
the destination of control flow bytecode is hardcoded when compiling, it seems impossible..

Comment: Looking through the op code table, it looks like `lookupswitch`, `tableswitch`, `ret`, and some `invoke` op codes will branch to addresses that need to be computed at runtime.  But I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish: "change my control flow at runtime"?  That's what IF statements are for.  What problem are you trying to solve that you need to be thinking about instruction-level control flow issues like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An indirect jump would fail the bytecode verifier. Read about how the class files are verified (in the [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9)) and you'll see why.

In particular, the following would be impossible to verify:

- The target of all control-flow instructions must be start of an instruction (no jumping into the middle of an instruction)
- The stack must be consistent (same height and types of values) at a particular instruction, no matter how the VM got to that point.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you a lot for your great reply! I am new to jvm related topic... so could you give some more explanation of "the stack must be consistent" statement... I am confused with that.... thank you !

Comment: Here is an example: whenever the instruction at offset 123 in some method is executed, the stack will always be have 3 elements in it, and they will always be: `<ref> <int> <ref>`. If somehow the stack could end up being `<ref> <ref>` or `<ref> <int> <ref> <int>` etc., the verifier will reject that classfile.The verifier does some pretty clever static analysis to make sure things are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Completely took the question wrongly. (See below)

JVM support goto at bytecode level. You just need libraries like 

## [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)

---

Original answer, on `goto` in source code:

Initially [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) had goto statements but later versions didnt had it. I think the possible reason could be `goto` is unnecessary and it can be replaced with more readable statements

The goto keyword exists, but it is not implemented.

Check this interesting video by [James Gosling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ei-rbULWoA&t=17m25s)

Comment: It still has `goto` keyword. However, it doesn't allow to use it.

Comment: @RohitJain:- Yes thats true but I think now it is not implemented.!

Comment: I'm referring to your first statement. Even later versions has it. You still can't declare a variable named `goto`. But you can't even use it.

Comment: It was never, ever meant to be implemented, it's reservation is to indicate that.

Comment: I just once watched this interesting video on this:- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ei-rbULWoA&t=17m25s

Comment: @RahulTripathi ok I stand corrected - goto has never been implemented in a publicly available version of Java =)

Comment: -1: Come on guys. He is talking about the Java Bytecode `goto` instruction. Not about a plain goto statement in source code.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux:- Completely got it wrong. Corrected my answer now. Does that make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Any form of method call is an "indirect jump" by your definition.

Comment: I think he means an address determined at runtime, a method call is a jump handled by the JVM all though it's not directed.

Comment: Thank you, I update my question, method call has a explicit destination I think, like "invokespecial #10", you can never change the #10, am i right?

Comment: @computereasy: you can use `invokedynamic` to produce an invocation whose target can be changed at runtime. Since the target is expressed as a `MethodHandle` instance, the `invokedynamic` can be (re)-directed not only to method calls but simple field accesses or object constructions, etc. This feature requires Java 7 or newer.